# Is there a way to fix Cannot read property 'post' of undefined?

Tags: vue.js, post, get

I'm running a page in vue with a form, it submits and returns data to and from an API, I'm getting a 'post' of undefined error in the console and I can't seem to figure out what's going on.

```
<script>
    methods: {
            StartClient: function () { // Initiate XMLHttpRequest as aHttpRequest for GET 
                this.get = function(Url, Callback){
                var aHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                aHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (aHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && aHttpRequest.status == 200)
                    Callback(aHttpRequest.responseText);
                }
                // use aHttpRequest with response headers, to allow GET
                aHttpRequest.open("GET", Url, true);
                aHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-Api-Key", "eVnbxBPfn01kuoJIdfgi46TiYNv8AIip1r3WbjsX");
                aHttpRequest.send(null);
            }
            this.post = function(Url, message, Callback) { // initiate XMLHttpRequest as aHttpRequest for POST
                var aHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                aHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (aHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && aHttpRequest.status == 200)
                    Callback(aHttpRequest.responseText);
                }
                // use aHttpRequest with response headers, to allow POST 
                aHttpRequest.open("POST", Url, true);
                aHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-Api-Key", "eVnbxBPfn01kuoJIdfgi46TiYNv8AIip1r3WbjsX");
                aHttpRequest.send(message);
                }
            },

        submitData: function () { // Start a traceroute, followed by the 'Begin' button 
            document.getElementById('inputBox').disabled = true;
            var targetInputButton = document.getElementById("inputBox").value;
            var message = '{"targetInputButton":"' + targetInputButton + '"}';
            this.StartClient().post('https://le75bkfcmg.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/start-trace', message, function(response) {
            document.getElementById('jobId').innerHTML = response;
        });
        },

        sendBackData: function () { // Receive traceroute data, followed by the 'Generate data' button
            var jobId = document.getElementById("jobId").innerHTML;
            var message = '{"jobId":"' + jobId + '"}';
            this.StartClient().post('https://le75bkfcmg.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/check-trace', message, function(response) {
            document.getElementById('report').innerHTML = response;
        });
        }
    }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your indentation is so erratic that it's impossible to tell what's going on. Best guess the problem is `this.StartClient().post` as `StartClient` doesn't return anything. Not really clear what you're trying to achieve, seems like the `StartClient` code might have been copied from elsewhere and was originally intended to be a constructor?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this, and yes StartClient is meant to be a constructor -->                var client = new StartClient();

Comment: Not the best solution but you can do something like:

if (this.StartClient()) this.StartClient().post

Comment: Thank you, I added that and it finally worked